# Convert ppt or pptx to pdf in linux with php

Tags: php

I want to convert ppt or pptx to pdf in linux with php and I am using following command

Using LibreOffice:

```
exec('soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:"draw_pdf_Export" /home/test/public_html/converted/presentation1.ppt',$o1,$r1);
```

Using OpenOffice:

```
exec("/usr/bin/openoffice.org -f pdf /home/yocook/public_html/converted/test.doc --outdir /home/yocook/public_html/converted",$output1,$ret1);
```

and both of them returns 0 which supposed to be true value but I can not find converted pdf files in the output directory. I did check folder permissions and set it to 755 and 777 still no files are written in the directory.

- My Linux version : 2.6.32
- PHP version : 5.3.13

Comment: Did you try to execute those commands by yourself in a terminal to see if the problem comes from PHP or not ?

Comment: also, you cannot trust ooo/lo return codes. they are always 0 in my experience, even when the most horrible errors (should have) happened -- like e.g. calling a nonexistent macro.

Comment: I don't have access to the terminal to execute the command directly as this is our test server and many projects are running under it. I will try to have the access first.

Answer (score 0):

If you access it via webserver, your webserver wwwrun may not have sufficient permissions to look into the yocook directory.

Try executing the php file from terminal with the command: `php convert.php`(where convert.php is the name of your file)

if it succesfully works then it's a permissions issue and you should use a public temp dir for your files.
If it still doesn't work try the commands directly in terminal and see if any errors occur, if it works perfectly try `su wwwadmin` and execute the command as wwwadmin and see what happens.

If it still works try to see in php.ini if the exec command is even allowed.

Comment: I don't have access to terminal. I checked with phpinfo and found exec listed under "disable_classes". I don't know if this is causing, and I am sure it is not permissions issue because I have one more command exec("convert /home/yocook/public_html/converted/test.pdf /home/yocook/public_html/converted/tt%d.png") which is working perfect and writing images to the output directory. I also tried with exec("su wwwadmin") and then libreoffice convert command but got 126 error code.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you might not have access to the openoffice or soffice executables.
Are you sure openoffice is installed under /usr/bin as openoffice.org symlink?
Try an `exec('ls /usr/bin > /home/yocook/public_html/contents.txt')` to see what actually is in /usr/bin

Comment: I found openoffice.org, openoffice.org-1.9, openoffice.org-2.0, libreoffice4.1, libreoffice4.1-printeradmin, soffice under /usr/bin and tried with all the commands still no output. How to check if I have access to openoffice or soffice executable?

Comment: Try `exec('ls -l /usr/bin > /home/yocook/public_html/contents.txt')`
You should see a lot of x's there and see your user group mentioned there, otherwise you cannot execute them. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-bsd-listing-permissions-of-file/

Comment: Thanks for this. I got this output -rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 82599 Sep 20 07:16 /home/yocook/public_html/contents.txt, I guess "nobody" doesn't have access to write and have lowest rights. How to change the group so that the user can write files?